# Issue in Exporting SSRS Reports with pivots in to CSV

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report in SSRS which I have build using report builder. So the thing is I want to have a pivot on the data and it works fine in the preview also when I export the rendered report into Excel. The issue comes up when I export the report into CSV. I have attached 4 images which will help in understanding my issue.
I am using a matrix to build the report which works fine when I export it into Excel.

[This is the output of the report when exported into excel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1bL6.png)
[This is the output of the report when exported into csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzpUR.png)

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is how the CSV export works. It is not pretty.

More often than not, when it comes to reports that are more than just simple tables of data, the CSV data is almost useless after export.

Your best bet would be to create a report that is a little more friendly toward CSV exports, or avoid exporting to CSV if you don't have to. Excel tends to work much better for most exports.

Comment: I have managed to make it very close to what I want. But, i would like to know how can I make rows appear as rows and not columns when I export the report to csv? 

I would like to show a grand total at the end which works well with an export to excel but again fails with CSV.

Comment: That is the point of the answer. You will have to build a CSV friendly report for that. The out of the box CSV export doesn't work well with matrix based reports.